# Толковый словарь русского языка для игры типа "Балда"

Tags: документация, книги, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго времени суток, уважаемое сообщество. Для очередной версии "Балды" ищется словарь в виде текстового файла, из которого можно извлечь **существительные** и их толкование для дальнейшего занесения в базу данных.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: просто база слов подойдёт?

Comment: Да, буду очень признателен.

Comment: http://ispell.narod.ru/

Answer (score 1):

[Такой](http://lib.ru/DIC/OZHEGOW/) пойдёт?